# Laravel: How to add header, footer and a logo image to a Excel export file?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, file, export

I am using MaatWebsite package.
Here is my Excel Export Class:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\AfterSheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithColumnFormatting;


class ReleaseExportView implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize, WithEvents
{
protected $shipment_id;
function __construct($shipment_id) {
    $this->shipment_id = $shipment_id;
}

public function collection()
{
  

    return outbound_detail::where('shipment_id',$this->shipment_id)->get([
        'shipment_id', 'sku_parent', 'cases'
    ]);
}

public function headings(): array
{
    return [

        'SHIPMENT ID',
        'SKU',
        'CASES TO BE RELEASED'
    ];
 }
 // ...

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function registerEvents(): array
{
    return [
        AfterSheet::class    => function(AfterSheet $event) {
            $cellRange = 'A1:C1'; // All headers
            $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getStyle($cellRange)->getFont()->setSize(14);
            },
    ];
}
 }
```

Now when I export this, it simply download an Excel file with given headers and data which is fetched from the DB. I want to add a Logo image on top (if possible), A header containing the information about company, i.e address etc and a footer with some text.

Comment: what have you attempted so far? have you looked into the documentation for the software you are using?

Comment: yes, i have looked but just couldn't figure it out, I have seen many people do what I am attempting to do, I just don't know how